# Remove Individual's eMail as default when sending eMails

Tags: email, default-settings

Sending ( not mass-sending ) of eMails:
the eMail address of th actual user is put to the send-from field.
Alternativley the organizations eMail address can ( and has to be selected
manually - this is error-prone ) 
Question: how can I make only our orgaizations eMail address to be displayed - or at least show this as default instead of the acual user's one?

best regards, Markus

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an option that CiviCRM provides out of the box.  If you have some jQuery skills or some PHP skills, it would only be a few lines of code to do what you're describing by [writing an extension](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+an+Extension).  If you don't have those skills, you may want to consider hiring someone who does, either a third party or the [core team](https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue).